# Best way in custom Spring Boot Starter library to read current properties and set new ones based on values

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I’m building a set of libraries on top of Spring Boot, packaged as Spring Boot Starters. I need to be able to define functionality where on application startup they look at the environment (i.e. read properties) and based on that will set other property values. I originally tried to do this in an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` but that doesn’t seem to be the correct place because you run into ordering issues where not all `PropertySource`s are available yet.

My specific use case is I want to look for for the presence of the `spring.boot.admin.client.url` property. If not found then set the property `spring.boot.admin.client.enabled=false`.

On the config server side we have different configurations for different apps with different profiles, some of which set  `spring.boot.admin.client.url` to a value and some which don't. The application itself bundles the `spring-boot-admin-starter-client` dependency regardless. Whether or not to enable it is simply driven by the application's runtime target.

I’m wondering what is the correct approach for this?

I thought about either an `ApplicationListener` or `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

The `ApplicationContextInitializer` is fired twice at startup, once for the bootstrap context & once for the main context. The `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` is fired twice (just before the call to each of the `ApplicationContextInitializer`s). At that point the config service property sources are not yet present and the property values I'm looking for are not yet present.

There is then a bunch of different `ApplicationPreparedEvent`s & `ApplicationStartedEvent`s fired (I counted 3 `ApplicationPreparedEvent`s (same instance id of the event), followed by 2 `ApplicationStartedEvent`s (same instance id of the event), followed by 2 `ApplicationReadyEvent`s (same instance id of the event)).

**UPDATED September 28, 2018**

I wanted to add on some of the tests I've tried as well. I built a blank application from the Spring Initializr. I built an `ApplicationContextInitializr` and an `ApplicationListener` as follows:

`application.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: TestEventStartup
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        url: http://localhost:8888
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
  resources:
    chain:
      strategy:
        content:
          enabled: true

logging:
  level:
    root: warn
    com.testeventstartup: debug

server:
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: application/json,text/css,text/html
    min-response-size: 2048

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  info:
    git:
      mode: full
```

```java
public class AppContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Initializing Context - Got spring.boot.admin.client.url=%s", applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("spring.boot.admin.client.url")));
    }
}

public class AppListener implements ApplicationListener<SpringApplicationEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SpringApplicationEvent event) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Got event: %s", ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(event)));

        findEnvironment(event)
            .ifPresent(environment -> System.out.println(String.format("%s: spring.boot.admin.client.url=%s", event.getClass().getSimpleName(), environment.getProperty("spring.boot.admin.client.url"))));
    }

    private Optional<Environment> findEnvironment(Object obj) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable(ReflectionUtils.findMethod(obj.getClass(), "getEnvironment"))
            .map(method -> ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, obj))
            .orElseGet(() ->
                Optional.ofNullable(ReflectionUtils.findMethod(obj.getClass(), "getApplicationContext"))
                    .map(method -> ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(method, obj))
                    .flatMap(this::findEnvironment)
                    .orElse(null)
            ))
            .filter(Environment.class::isInstance)
            .map(Environment.class::cast);
    }
}
```

`/META-INF/spring.factories`:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
com.testeventstartup.listener.AppListener

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
com.testeventstartup.listener.AppContextInitializer
```

When I start up the application without the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency, I see this in my log:

```
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartingEvent@32709393[args={},timestamp=1538141292580]
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent@399f45b1[environment=StandardServletEnvironment {activeProfiles=[], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[StubPropertySource {name='servletConfigInitParams'}, StubPropertySource {name='servletContextInitParams'}, MapPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}, OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}, RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}, OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml] (document #1)'}]},args={},timestamp=1538141292628]
ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8888

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

Initializing Context - Got spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8888
2018-09-28 09:28:12.918  INFO 2534 --- [           main] c.t.TestEventStartupApplication          : Starting TestEventStartupApplication on MAC-22XG8WL with PID 2534 (/Users/edeandre/workspaces/IntelliJ/test-event-startup/build/classes/java/main started by edeandre in /Users/edeandre/workspaces/IntelliJ/test-event-startup)
2018-09-28 09:28:12.920 DEBUG 2534 --- [           main] c.t.TestEventStartupApplication          : Running with Spring Boot v2.0.5.RELEASE, Spring v5.0.9.RELEASE
2018-09-28 09:28:12.922  INFO 2534 --- [           main] c.t.TestEventStartupApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@6a370f4[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@49e53c76: startup date [Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969]; root of context hierarchy,args={},timestamp=1538141292961]
ApplicationPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8888
2018-09-28 09:28:15.385  INFO 2534 --- [           main] c.t.TestEventStartupApplication          : Started TestEventStartupApplication in 2.809 seconds (JVM running for 3.32)
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartedEvent@7159139f[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@49e53c76: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:28:12 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy,args={},timestamp=1538141295385]
ApplicationStartedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8888
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent@232cce0[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@49e53c76: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:28:12 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy,args={},timestamp=1538141295387]
ApplicationReadyEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8888
```

When I then add in the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency and wire in my config server, this is what I see at startup:

```
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartingEvent@23faf8f2[args={},timestamp=1538141399719]
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartingEvent@306279ee[args={},timestamp=1538141399814]
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent@7cc0cdad[environment=StandardEnvironment {activeProfiles=[], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource {name='configurationProperties'}, MapPropertySource {name='bootstrap'}, MapPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}, OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}, RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}, MapPropertySource {name='springCloudClientHostInfo'}, OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='applicationConfig: [classpath:/bootstrap.yml]'}]},args={},timestamp=1538141399815]
ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=null
Initializing Context - Got spring.boot.admin.client.url=null
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@4e7912d8[context=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f: startup date [Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969]; root of context hierarchy,args={},timestamp=1538141400176]
ApplicationPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=null
2018-09-28 09:30:00.183  INFO 2568 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:00 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-28 09:30:00.362  INFO 2568 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f1570cbf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@4e7912d8[context=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:00 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy,args={},timestamp=1538141400176]
ApplicationPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=null
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartedEvent@460ebd80[context=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:00 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy,args={},timestamp=1538141400608]
ApplicationStartedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=null
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent@16fdec90[context=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:00 EDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy,args={},timestamp=1538141400609]
ApplicationReadyEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=null
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent@e8df99a[environment=StandardServletEnvironment {activeProfiles=[], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[ConfigurationPropertySourcesPropertySource {name='configurationProperties'}, StubPropertySource {name='servletConfigInitParams'}, StubPropertySource {name='servletContextInitParams'}, MapPropertySource {name='systemProperties'}, OriginAwareSystemEnvironmentPropertySource {name='systemEnvironment'}, RandomValuePropertySource {name='random'}, OriginTrackedMapPropertySource {name='applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml] (document #1)'}, ExtendedDefaultPropertySource {name='defaultProperties'}, MapPropertySource {name='springCloudClientHostInfo'}]},args={},timestamp=1538141399781]
ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8888

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

Initializing Context - Got spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
2018-09-28 09:30:01.683  INFO 2568 --- [           main] c.t.TestEventStartupApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@5c87bfe2[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2eee3069: startup date [Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f,args={},timestamp=1538141401690]
ApplicationPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@5c87bfe2[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2eee3069: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:01 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f,args={},timestamp=1538141401690]
ApplicationPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@5c87bfe2[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2eee3069: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:01 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f,args={},timestamp=1538141401690]
ApplicationPreparedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
2018-09-28 09:30:03.858  INFO 2568 --- [           main] c.t.TestEventStartupApplication          : Started TestEventStartupApplication in 4.143 seconds (JVM running for 4.88)
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartedEvent@3dfa819[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2eee3069: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:01 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f,args={},timestamp=1538141403859]
ApplicationStartedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartedEvent@3dfa819[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2eee3069: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:01 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f,args={},timestamp=1538141403859]
ApplicationStartedEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent@4ce94d2f[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2eee3069: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:01 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f,args={},timestamp=1538141403861]
ApplicationReadyEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
Got event: org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent@4ce94d2f[context=org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2eee3069: startup date [Fri Sep 28 09:30:01 EDT 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@815b41f,args={},timestamp=1538141403861]
ApplicationReadyEvent: spring.boot.admin.client.url=https://myspringbootadminserver.mycompany.com
```

You'll notice a few things once hooking into the config server:

1. The `ApplicationContextInitializer` fires twice - once for the bootstrap & once for the "main" application

   - When the "main" application fires the properties are all resolved
2. The various [lifecycle events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners) are fired multiple times

   - If you look closely though, the same instance of the events are fired multiple times (i.e. `org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@732c2a62` (fired twice), `org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationPreparedEvent@6b9ce1bf` (fired 3 times), `org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationStartedEvent@1f6917fb` (fired twice), `org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent@41eb94bc` (fired twice)

I understand that the [lifecycle events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners) should be fired twice, once for the bootstrap context and the "main" context, but within each context's lifecycle, why is the same instance of the event fired multiple times?

Furthermore - this whole thing is leading me down the path towards feeling like my solution here should be that I should use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` as the best solution to my requirement (inspect the current `Environment` for current state of property values then conditionally set a property value/add an additional `PropertySource`. If my requirement is just to programmatically add property values, then continuing to use `EnvironmentPostProcessor` is probably the better solution.

The downside now is that the logic in `ApplicationContextInitializer` happens twice, once in each context. Is there a way for an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to understand for which context it is running in and then only actually do what we want in the "main" one?

Can someone please weigh in on my observations? @AndyWilkinson?

Comment: A description of the higher-level problem that you're facing would be useful as there may be better approaches than setting properties based on the value of other properties.

Comment: @andy-wilkinson I added some more context

Comment: If you are using Spring Cloud, you may be seeing multiple events because it creates an application context hierarchy (it uses a separate context for bootstrapping). You should be able to filter the events based on their application context.

Comment: I guess my 1st question is would using some kind of ApplicationListener be the correct solution for what I'm trying to accomplish? If so, is there something on the ApplicationContext that could be examined to determine whether to respond to the event? I did notice the events of each type did have the same instance id, meaning the same instance if the same event was caught multiple times for some reason.

Comment: See additional information I added to the original post

Comment: The exact same lifecycle event being published multiple times sounds like a bug to me. I'd guess that it's a bug in Spring Cloud, but I can't be 100% sure of that. Can you please raise an issue with a small sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I submitted https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14656

Comment: @AndyWilkinson back to my original question (forgetting about multiple events fired/received) - before beans are created I need to inspect the current environment and then based on the current values of properties I need to set values of other properties. I need the property sources from all sources fully resolved as well.

Would an `ApplicationContextInitializer` that only runs in the "main" context be the correct place to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't do it at all as it's always going to be brittle. You can't stop someone manipulating the environment after your logic has run. If you really want to do it, I'd use an `ApplicationListener` for `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` with low or even lowest precedence. If that doesn't work in your situation then something is manipulating the environment later than is typically expected. That really just shows the brittleness of what you're trying to do. I'd recommend taking a step back and re-thinking things.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson even at lowest precedence, an `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` runs before any `configService` property sources are added. I'm open to re-thinking the approach but the underlying requirement is the same - As a framework library on the runtime classpath of an application I need to be able to inspect the current environment and set property values based on various conditions (current environment values, classes on the classpath) so that I can influence auto-configuration choices. Are you questioning the requirement itself or the implementation of it?

Comment: If no config service properties are available at that point, I'd argue that's a Spring Cloud problem. Perhaps they have good reason for not using an environment post-processor. I'm questioning the wisdom of setting properties depending on what other properties have been configured. It's always going to be brittle, irrespective of how you implement it. You'll always want to go last so that you can get a complete view of the environment, but what happens if someone else has the same requirement? They can't go last as well so someone is going to have to live with an incomplete view.

Comment: The thought we had is for us to go in "almost-last" - with a very low precedence but not lowest. This way if someone so chooses to override what we've done then so be it - they should win. Very much similar conceptually to auto-configuration. Provide sensible defaults but back off if/when someone else wants to override. Depending on the particular use case - we also check to make sure the property we are trying to set hasn't yet already been defined when we examine it. Most of the time we are setting defaults of things based on other things, but if something is already set we leave things be.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Spring application Events and Listeners. In your case, you can use `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`like:

```
public class OverridePropertiesListener implements 
        ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("myProperty", "<my value>");
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("myProps", props));
   }
}
```

For more information on listeners: [Application Events and Listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners)

Comment: `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` would be fine if I only wanted to add properties. My requirement is I need to inspect the set of resolved properties first, then based on what is found, conditionally set a property value. The `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` is too soon in the lifecycle as the `Environment` is not yet fully resolved. `ApplicationPreparedEvent` is also too late because according to the javadocs the bean definitions will be loaded. I need to be able to set the properties before bean loading happens, since values of properties can affect which beans are loaded.

Comment: In a plain Boot app this will work nicely, particularly if you give your listener for `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` a really low or even lowest precedence.

Comment: Agreed - in a plain boot app that doesn't "solicit" properties from a `configService` `PropertySource` then yes this would be perfect. Unfortunately (maybe this is a bug in Spring Cloud?) this approach fails under that use case.

Comment: @Eric You can register your `AppContextInitializer` as bean, then it will be registered only in main context.